# Nginx 404-error on subdirectories of Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server, multisite

I migrate my wordpress multisite to VPS with Nginx and get 404 nginx error on every subdirectories  - mysite.com/subdir , exclude /wp-admin .
It's my Nginx virtual host configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
root /var/www/mysite.com/html;

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com mysite.com/subsite;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

}
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Thank you for help!